# What's the lates stable kernel version compatible with the latest nvidia drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, 21.04

My question is simple.
What's the lates stable kernel version compatible with the latest nvidia drivers?

I use kubuntu 21.04 with 5.11.0-18-generic kernel

```
Inxi -G

Graphics: 

Device-1: Intel TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel 
           
Device-2: NVIDIA TU117M [GeForce MX450] driver: nvidia v: 470.57.02 
           
Device-3: Luxvisions Innotech Limited HP Wide Vision HD Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
           
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded:  fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           
OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce MX450/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.57.02
```

Comment: The kernel will not be pushed unless it's considered to be stable.  Kernels that have not been pushed yet are still in testing. Are you experiencing a problem?  If so, you should ask about the actual problem that you are facing and provide details about that problem.  If you have encountered a bug, you should file a bug report

Comment: FWIW I am running kernel 5.13.12 with NVidia 470.63.01 with no issues...

Comment: @andrew.46 thanks for the suggestion. but i have 1 question, how do i install that kernel? I'm used to installing like sudo apt install linux-image-5.x.x-x-generic but when i try to install that kernel i dosen't work.

Comment: @SuperVidak64 I confess that I build my own kernels, this gives greater flexibility with such things...